# Extracting only part of an integer from a cell and copying it into a seperate column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of numbers that have the form 1234567 or 1234567-1 or 1234567A1 or 123456-1. I need to loop through that column and create a separate column(column B) that has the core number. By that I mean for 1234567-1 it has 1234567 in column B. For 1234567 it has 1234567, 1234567A1 I need that entire number 1234567A1. Pretty much if a dash appears I need the characters before the dash. If a letter appears I need the whole thing(unless theres a dash). And otherwise I just need the first 7 numbers.

```
Sub UpdatePartNumber()


Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long



lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


On Error Resume Next
Next c
For i = 2 To lastRow

Cells("A" & i).Select
LeftSeven = Left(Selection, 7)

    If Selection <> 0 Then
        Cells("B" & i).Value = LeftSeven
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the dash and if its there get the contents up to it if not grab the entire thing, see below with comments.

```
Sub UpdatePartNumber()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim dashLocation As Integer

      'get the last row
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next

For i = 2 To lastRow
    'get the location of the dash, if there is one
    dashLocation = InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "-")
    'check for dash and if it is there grab all digits up to it
    If dashLocation > 0 Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, dashLocation - 1)
    Else
    'no dash so grab entire contents
    Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, it can be a good idea to fully qualify the range: `Sheet1.Cells(i, x).Value = ...`

Comment: up ticked as that is a great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop through the range to do this, allowing you to `Offset` your location and eliminating some lines of code.

Be careful about using `On Error Resume Next`. Translated it means "Ignore any runtime error and proceed with the next line of code".  Sometimes this is the behavior you want, but improperly used it can leave bugs unnoticed and cause unexpected problems down the line.

```
Sub UpdatePartNumber()

    '~~> dim variables and set initial values
        Dim rngNumberColumn As Range
            Set rngNumberColumn = activeworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2", _
                                    activeworkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        Dim rngCell As Range
        Dim strNumber As String

    '~~> loop to extract core number
        For Each rngCell In rngNumberColumn
            strNumber = rngCell.value
            If InStr(strNumber, "-") > 0 Then
                strNumber = Left(strNumber, InStr(strNumber, "-") - 1)
            End If
            rngCell.Offset(0, 1).value = strNumber
        Next rngCell

End Sub
```